# assign collection name at runtime in Mongoose save

Tags: mongoose

Is it possible to provide `collection` name at runtime instead of hard coding it when creating the `schema`?

Eg, instead of

```
const questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    description: String,
    hints: [String],
    topic: String
}, { collection : 'area' });
```

do

```
const questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    description: String,
    hints: [String],
    topic: String
}, { collection : variablename });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is possible, and even if it was, I would think it's a dark pattern.

If you have to have multiple collections, which have the same schema but **dynamic** names, I think you should instead do:

```js
const questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    type: String, // Type of question, e.g. "area"
    description: String,
    hints: [String],
    topic: String
}, { collection : variablename });
```

If instead, those names are not dynamic.

You can define all of them in the same file, and I don't think this would be a bad thing:

```js
const questionsAreaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    description: String,
    hints: [String],
    topic: String
}, { collection : 'questions-area' });

const questionsFooSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    description: String,
    hints: [String],
    topic: String
}, { collection : 'questions-foo' });
```

To avoid duplication, you could even factor the `{description, hints, topic}` object into a separate constant.